# Horizontal parallax scrolling to centered div

Tags: navigation, center, parallax

I'm building a website with a horizontal parallax effect, unsing this script: http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/

But I want to put in a navigation to scroll to a specific item, that centers on the screen. For example: Clicking a link scrolls the page horizontally to a div, that then is horizontally centered in the browser window.

Maybe it can be combined with something like that:
http://stereobit.github.io/dragend/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to achieve the same effect; but i am struggling with the anchor links and linking them to the parallax effect. I created the horizontal effect using tables added through jquery, coupled with jquery.mousewheel to bind the scroll wheel to the horizontal bar (instead of the jInvertScroll, which still displays a vertical scrollbar). Still not satisfied though, as it works kinda bad.

For your question about centering: I have no idea how you define your code, but: if you have each page at 100% screen size, so each content page you have requires a full width scroll, you can use either:
- calculate in ajvascript the screen width, then use scrollLeft to move that width left or right
- use jquery .next (your next element) and .prev (orevious element) to scroll through pages

I am going to try and use the second one in my attempt; I have no idea though how to link the parallax scrolling to this way. Perhaps something with calculating the exact position of divs on screen and use that to calculate the parallax effect onto it, but it would break other resolutions i think